# Polygon with wrong coordinates order

Tags: polygon

I'm playing to grow a polygon from a CLLocationCoordinate2D array.
This is the code:

```
int coordsLen = [self.coordinatesArray count];
CLLocationCoordinate2D *coords = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * coordsLen);
NSLog(@"count: %d", coordsLen);
for (int i=0; i < coordsLen; i++)
{
    coordinates *coordObj = (coordinates *)[self.coordinatesArray objectAtIndex:i];
    coords[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordObj.latitude, coordObj.longitude);
}
self.polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coords count:coordsLen];
free(coords);
```

The result is that instead show me a rectangle (as the order of the coordinates into the self.coordatesArray is) it shows me an hourglass.

Even if I use the fromPoint constructor, I got the same result:

```
int coordsLen = [self.coordinatesArray count];
MKMapPoint points[coordsLen];
for (int i=0; i < coordsLen; i++)
{
    coordinates *coordObj = (coordinates *)[self.coordinatesArray objectAtIndex:i];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D c = {coordObj.latitude,coordObj.longitude};
    points[i] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(c);
}

self.polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:points count:coordsLen];
```

This is how I add the polygon as overlay to the map:

```
self.polygonView = nil;
[self.mapView addOverlay:self.polygon];
[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.polygon boundingMapRect] animated:TRUE];
```

These are the coordinates:

```
coord1 =     {
    latitude = "45.546112";
    longitude = "9.11805";
};
coord2 =     {
    latitude = "45.545773";
    longitude = "9.120568";
};
coord3 =     {
    latitude = "45.544468";
    longitude = "9.120629";
};
coord4 =     {
    latitude = "45.544544";
    longitude = "9.118";
};
```

Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance,
Samuel

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the returned recordset I get with coords it was saved in a NSDictionary, that it doesn't have an order.
Using a counter from the recordset, I created a NSMutableArray, reaching my goal.

Samuel